# How can I copy specific range values in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

How can I copy specific range values in Excel VBA?
I'm trying to copy a range by first creating an inputbox for the user to enter the range in another workbook, then copy that range's values from all the selected workbooks into one workbook.

This is what I have, but it copies only one set of values.

```
    FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Filter (*.csv), *.csv", Title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=True)
    nw = UBound(FileNames)
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(1)
    Set UserRange = Application.InputBox(Title:="Select Range", Prompt:="Range", Default:=DefaultRange, Type:=8)
    For i = 1 To nw
Set FileNames(i) = ActiveWorkbook
        UserRange.Copy
        tWB.Worksheets("Data").range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Next i
```

Edit: I need to only open one workbook, define UserRange as the range, and copy the values in that range in all selected workbooks, then paste them into the tWB workbook.

Comment: So many things can go wrong when you use `InputBox` - and also, you need to check the Filename to see if it's blank in case the users cancels it too... This is not a great approach.

Comment: braX, unfortunately I have to use Inputbox.  The inputbox defines the range that should be copied and pasted from each workbook selected from Application.GetOpenFileName. The problem I am having is that instead of copying different values from each workbook, it only copies the values of the first workbook and pastes it x times (x being how many files I selected)

Comment: That's because that is exactly how your code is written. `UserRange` never changes and you never open a new workbook (opening should be inside the loop).

Comment: @BigBen I need UserRange to remain the same range, I only need to change which workbook that range is in to get each workbook's values. This should only open one workbook such that I can define the range that will be used in all workbooks that were selected.

Comment: Use `UserRange.Address` then. You'll still need a loop to open the other workbooks

Comment: @BigBen, I don't want the code to open every workbook, only one such that a range can be set for the other workbooks. Also, where can I put UserRange.Address? It runs into an error 'Invalid Qualifier' If I try to add that.

Comment: You need a loop to open "all selected workbooks" per your instructions. `Application.GetOpenFilename` doesn't open the workbooks you've selected.

Comment: @BigBen, I've added a loop to open each workbook, and the results are now accurate - Thank you! Each workbook I selected opens individually, which allows the code to copy the different values each time.

Comment: Good stuff! Cheers and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

As posted by BigBen in the comments, I've changed the code to open each workbook individually and copy the values each time. This gives the accurate results I was looking for.

The new code looks like this:

```
FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Filter (*.csv), *.csv", Title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=True)
nw = UBound(FileNames)
For i = 1 To nw
    Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
    Set UserRange = Application.InputBox(Title:="Select Range", Prompt:="Range", Type:=8)
    UserRange.Copy
    tWB.Worksheets("Data").range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next i
```